# Comparing the behavior of two "similar" solutions of I.V.P

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function, initial-value-problems

Here is the ode I'm interested in:

> $\frac{ \partial y}{\partial x}=
>  (1+y)^{\frac{3}{4}}(1-y)^{\frac{3}{4}}\;$

**I would like to know, in which way and when, the solution of the above ode approaches $\;\pm 1$.**

*My attempt:*

Since the solution cannot be expressed in closed form (the solution according to *Wolfram Alpha* is given by : $c+x=y(x)_2F_1(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4};\frac{3}{2};{y(x)}^2)\;)$, my professor suggested to compare the behavior of the above solution when $y\sim 1\;$ with the solution of the following I.V.P:

> $\frac{ \partial q}{\partial s}=4q^{3/4}\;\\q(0)=0\;$

by setting $q=1-y\;$

I have no idea how should I proceed. I solved the problem (which hasn't a unique solution because the Lipschitz condition isn't satisfied) but I have no clue how to compare this solution to the first one, in order to find more information.

I would really appreciate if somebody could help me through this. How should I handle similar to this, problems? Is there something I should check or calculate first?

I'm totally lost, so any help would be valuable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried the change of variable $y = \sin u?$

Comment: @abel I suppose you refer to the first ode. I tried but the solution then, is in terms of elliptic integral and so it isn't also in closed form

Comment: i was.  i tried eulers method with initial condition $y = 0$ at $x = 0.$ the graph looks like a scaled version of arctangent approaching the stable equilibrium point $y = 0.$

Comment: @abel so you did a numerical approximation, if I understood correctly..  How does this connects with the solution in terms oj hypergeometric function? If you have time, would it be easy for you to post an answer and explain it to me? I don't know much about numerical approximations.. thanks a lot anyways